# How comes that function gets elements without parameters?

Tags: javascript

I would like to understand why my console.log outputs the elements which have been placed before `some()`.

```js
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
    console.log(element);
  return element > 10;
}

[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].some(isBiggerThan10);
```

From my understanding, the elements should be outputted if they are given as parameters of `isBiggerThan10()`. I guess this is because of the array function `some()`. If so, how can I write a similar code like what `some()` does? The goal is to output all elements of the array in the function myElements(). myElements should be a parameter of the function test().

This is what I have tried:

```js
Array.prototype.test = function(i) {
    console.log(i);
};

function myElements(element) {
    console.log(element);
}

[2, 5, 8, 1, 4].test(myElements);
```

But it seems like that I don't understand the logic behind of it.

Comment: see [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Comment: `test()` has to call the function you passed to it (in `i` hence that's a terrible name for it) for every element in the array and pass this element, the index and the array itself to `i` (have a look at the [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some#Polyfill) for `.some()`)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The syntax of `Array.prototype.some()` function specifies that you call `some()` over an array, and it takes for parameters a callback function (`function isBiggerThan10()` in your snippet), which itself takes one argument and 3 other optional ones. The main argument required is `element` which, is the value of each element that you iterate over from the array that calls `some()`. You can check the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some).

> Syntax
>
> ---
>
> ```
> arr.some(callback(element[, index[, array]])[, thisArg])
> ```
>
> Parameters
>
> ---
>
> **callback**: A function to test for each element, taking three arguments:
>
> **element**: The current element being processed in the array.

TLDR: `some()` iterates through each element of the array until condition is met, and the `element` argument in the callback function holds the value of the current element that is being iterated.

Answer (score 1):

some() method is used to check a condition on all array elements (or specified elements) and returns true if any of the array elements matches the condition and returns false if all array elements do not match the condition.

In case why all the element is being printed?, It is the fact that when you call the function you have console logged it, that's it .

so if you want to output all the numbers greater than 10 you can use the filter method.

```
function isBiggerThan10(element, index, array) {
return element > 10;
 }

 console.log([2, 5, 8, 1, 4].filter(isBiggerThan10))
```

Answer (score 0):

some function calls your isBiggerThan10 function for every element of the array. That's why all array elements are printed to console.
 Please refer https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some for more details